# How to Perform 2 Different Action in One Button?

Tags: flutter, dart

Example
How to open the url together with the snackbar in One button?

```
 onTap: () => launch("http://flutter.dev"),
 // when button tapped then url will be open and displaying a snackbar at a time
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discard the **arrow function** and write it like this

```
     onTap: (){
        launch("http://flutter.dev");
        Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Message here"),));
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

`onTap: () {
  firstFunction();
  secondFunction();
},`

Please comment if I misunderstood your question.